# Find all documents with a different value for a field with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection where each document represents a URL with a field for the hostname and one for the path.

Obviously there are many documents with the same hostname and I would like to retrieve one of them for each hostname.

For exemple if these are my documents

```
{
  "hostname" : "google.com",
  "path" : "/index.html"
},
{
  "hostname" : "google.com",
  "path" : "/page2.html"
},
{
  "hostname" : "facebook.com",
  "path" : "/"
},
{
  "hostname" : "facebook.com",
  "path" : "/user.php"
}
```

I would like to have in total two documents: one document for google.com (whichever one) and one for facebook.com (also whichever one.)

The only ways I could think of where to use findOne and gradually adding the retrieved hostnames to the list I passed as `{hostname: {$nin : alreadyRetrieved}}` in my queries.
Or I could get every document and then filter as I please. 
But those two methods are very slow so I sincerely hope there is another way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$group` in an aggregate pipeline like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$hostname",
      "path": {
        "$first": "$path"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This query group values by hostname and get the first path.
I've used `$first` because you want whichever one, but you can get all paths using `$push` instead of `$first`.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UyhCb2o3sAo)

Answer (score 0):

Use [distinct(fieldName)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```
db.collection.distinct('hostname')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only returns the different hostnames, I would like it to return one of the document associated with them. Or at least the path.

Comment: You will have to use aggregations in that case. No other way. @J.F. already posted your desired answer.